# display dynamic keys and values from json into xaml

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Below is my json

```
{"Hello":[{"CompanyName":"one","ETA":"10","Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 12","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"},{"CompanyName":"one","ETA":"10","Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 15","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"}],"ChildPresent":true}
```

I am deserialising everything and my main problem is with Invoice object ( `"Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 15","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"}]` ) which contains bunch of keys and values...the problem is with the keys inside "Invoice" object which changes after every 6 hours...And i need to display both keys and values in xaml

right now i am deserialising the above json everything into Modal and i am storing Invoice object data into Dictionary

```
RootObject j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

public class Hello 
{

    public Dictionary<string, string> Invoice { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    public string ETA {get;set;}
}

public class RootObject
{

    public List<Hello> Hello { get; set; }
    public bool ChildPresent { get; set; }
}
```

When I write in XAML `{Binding Invoice[TF1]}` I get the value of `TF1` but I want the key `TF1` to be displayed in the XAML.

My XAML Code

```
<Page x:Class="App13.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:App13"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      xmlns:converter="using:App13"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Grid  Margin="0,30.333,0,-0.333" Background="Black">
    <ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsEnabled="True"
              ItemClick="listview1_ItemClick"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding Hello}"
              FontSize="17" Margin="10,0,-10,0">
      <ListView.Items>
        </StackPanel>
      </ListView.Items>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Border Tapped="Border_Tap" Height="90">
              <StackPanel x:Name="ParentStackPanel"
                          Width="380" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                <StackPanel Background="Black"
                            Margin="60,-80,0,0" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}" 
                             FontSize="20" 
                             FontStyle="Normal">
                  </TextBlock>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ETA}" 
                             FontSize="16" 
                             FontStyle="Normal">
                  </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,-80,0,0" 
                            Background="Black" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                  <Image Width="48"  
                         Height="48"  
                         Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="expand" 
                            Background="White" 
                            Height="220">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                              Margin="10,10,0,0">
                    <TextBlock AllowDrop="True" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Margin="50,0,0,0" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               FontSize="10" 
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               Text="{Binding Invoice[TF1].Key}">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="tb" 
                               Grid.Column="2" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                               AllowDrop="True" 
                               FontSize="6" 
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               Width="204" 
                               Text="{Binding Path=Invoice[TF1]}">
                    </TextBlock>
                  </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                            Height="5"  
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Background="Aqua" 
                            x:Name="something">
                </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Where do you get TF1 key in xaml? is it hardcoded value?

Comment: yes my In my listview i have taken textblock... <textblock text="{Binding Invoice[TF1]}" /> it gives valu of TF1

Comment: Please provide XAML code. Also, `Dictionary<T, T>` is a bad solution for binding because it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so you won't see the changes you do with the dictionary.

Comment: I have added my xaml code in the edited question...

Comment: I don't understand. You are hardcoding the "TF1" value of the key in the XAML, then why don't you display directly "TF1" in your textblock? What's the point of trying to do `Text="{Binding Invoice[TF1].Key}"` when you could do `Text="TF1"`?

Comment: bcoz my json keys inside invoice object changes after every 6 hours...thats why i cannot hardcode it...after 6 hours TF1 may bcom WORLDBANK or IMF we cant predict

Comment: Then how do you know which one you need to display? Or if you want to display all key/values, you need to put a ListView or an ItemsControl somewhere.... The only one you have right now in your xaml is bound to `Hello`, not to `Invoice`

Comment: since Invoice is a member of hello...i think Invoice dont need to be bound again because when i do <textblock text="{Binding Invoice[TF1]}" it gives value...so i dont think there is need to bind again to Invoice....
why u think that i need to bound to Invoice ???

Comment: I want to display all keys and values of invoice json object

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?

Comment: no its only windows phone 8.1